# export * as blabla - unexpected token error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs

i am trying to run the jsx-version of some component i got from github.

what i get is this error though:

[image]

from what i've gathered this has something to do with my babel setup so i am also posting my .babelrc:

```
{
  "presets": [
    "flow",
    "es2015",
    "react",
    "stage-1"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "react-hot-loader/babel"
  ]
 }
```

i never had to change any babel settings so far (i am using react-create-app) and would appreciate any help or nudge into the right direction!

Comment: @yury tarabanko thx for pointing me to a fix!

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such thing as `export * as`. Maybe you are mistaken with the `import * as` statement.

What you probably want to do is `export * from './module'`.

You can read more about the export statement [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export).

Comment: this is the code from the module on github https://github.com/tsuyoshiwada/react-stack-grid/blob/master/src/index.js, it uses the export statement in conjunction with *